# How can I multiply two numbers?

Tags: calculations, pgffor

I use `pgffor` package and I have

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{**something I want**}
```

How can I print n*(n+1) for each n?

When I write just `\n*(\n+1)` instead of `**something I want**`,

```
1(1+1)2(2+1)3(3+1)...
```

appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{%
  \texttt{Something you want : \the\numexpr\x*(\x+1)/2\relax}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Please post compilable or at least copy/pastable code so that we can see what you want to do. Until then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \evalx using int(\x*(\x+1)/2)] in {1,...,10}{
\texttt{Something you want : \evalx}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since PGF and PGFPlots are getting married to Lua as well, here is another example in LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
for n = 1,10 do
 tex.sprint(n*(n+1)/2 ..', ')
 end
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A more flexible solution with `fp` just for fun. My example below uses an extreme case which is `f(x)=sin(x*π/10)` instead of your simple case which is `f(x)=x*(x+1)/2`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

%\def\f[#1]{#1*(#1+1)/2}% f:x --> x*(x+1)/2
\def\f[#1]{sin(#1*pi/10)}% XTreme case just for generalization

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}{%
    \FPset\x{\i}%
    \FPeval\y{\f[x]}%
    \FPeval\y{round(y:3)}% you can use 0 to get an integer
    $f(\i) = \y$ \par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

For your case.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\def\f[#1]{#1*(#1+1)/2}% f:x --> x*(x+1)/2
%\def\f[#1]{sin(#1*pi/10)}% 

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
    \FPset\x{\i}%
    \FPeval\y{\f[x]}%
    \FPeval\y{round(y:0)}%
    $f(\i) = \y$ \par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here is an example using the TeX primitive integer arithmetic operators and the plain TeX `\loop` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\n\newcount\tn
\def\triangles#1{1%
\n=1
\loop\ifnum\n<#1
\advance \n  by 1 \tn=\n
\advance \tn by 1 
\multiply\tn by \n
\divide  \tn by 2
, \number\tn \repeat}
\begin{document}
\triangles{15}.
\end{document}
```

[image]