# How can i change the label of y-axis in my graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here in my MWE, you will find a histogram. In which i would like to change labeling of y-axis. I want {10, 20, 30, .....100} in place of {1 , 2 , ..10}
Please make correction in same as well as provide any other alternate for changing and making axis label in smooth way.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (-1cm,0cm) -- (15cm,0cm) node [right] {\large$x$};  %Abzisse

    \draw[<->] (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,15cm) node [left] {\large$y$};  %Ordinate

    \foreach \x in {1,...,14}
    \draw[gray!50, text=black] (0 cm,\x cm) -- (14 cm,\x cm) 
    node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\x};

    \draw (1cm,0cm) rectangle (2cm,3cm) node at (1.5cm,3.4cm) {14};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (1cm,0cm) rectangle (2cm,3cm)
    node at (1.5cm,3.4cm) {14};

    \draw (2cm,0cm) rectangle (3cm,3cm) node at (2.5cm,3.4cm) {56};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (3cm,3cm)
    node at (2.5cm,3.4cm) {56};

    \draw (3cm,0cm) rectangle (4cm,3cm) node at (3.5cm,3.4cm) {60};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (3cm,0cm) rectangle (4cm,3cm)
    node at (3.5cm,3.4cm) {60};

    \draw (4cm,0cm) rectangle (5cm,3cm) node at (4.5cm,3.4cm) {86};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (4cm,0cm) rectangle (5cm,3cm)
    node at (4.5cm,3.4cm) {86};

    \draw (5cm,0cm) rectangle (6cm,3cm) node at (5.5cm,3.4cm) {74};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (5cm,0cm) rectangle (6cm,3cm)
    node at (5.5cm,3.4cm) {74};

    \draw (6cm,0cm) rectangle (7cm,3cm) node at (6.5cm,3.4cm) {62};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (6cm,0cm) rectangle (7cm,3cm)
    node at (6.5cm,3.4cm) {62};

    \draw (7cm,0cm) rectangle (8cm,3cm) node at (7.5cm,3.4cm) {48};

    \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

    \draw[fill=myblue] (7cm,0cm) rectangle (8cm,3cm)
    node at (7.5cm,3.4cm) {48};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to add `\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}` every time; you just need to use it once, at the beginning, and then it will be defined throughout your document.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you. You can avoid writing the same stuff several times.

I use `\the\numexpr\x*10` for calculating the labels and then each bar according with your design.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (-1cm,0cm) -- (15cm,0cm) node [right] {\large $x$};  %Abzisse


\draw[<->] (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,15cm) node [left] {\large $y$};  %Ordinate

\foreach \x in {1,...,14}
\draw[gray!50, text=black] (0 cm,\x cm) -- (14 cm,\x cm) node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) 
        {\the\numexpr\x*10};

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{92dcec}

\foreach \y [count=\x from 1] in {14, 56, 60, 36, 74, 62, 48} 
    {\draw[fill=myblue] (\x,0) rectangle (\x + 1, \y / 10);
    \node at (\x+.5,\y / 10 + .4) {\y};};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

This is the output:

[image: histogram]

Comment: A big big thanks to you.......i find something new hints from this .

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
 \foreach \x / \y in {
   1/10,
   2/20,
   3/30,
   4/40,
   5/50,
   6/60,
   7/70,
   8/80,
   9/90,
   10/100,
   11/110,
   12/120,
   13/130,
   14/140
 }
 \draw[gray!50, text=black] (0 cm,\x cm) -- (14 cm,\x cm) 
 node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\y};
```

This solution allows you to put whatever you want in this y-axis label.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `0` to the text at each node on your *y*-axis:

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,14}
\draw[gray!50, text=black] (0 cm,\x cm) -- (14 cm,\x cm) 
node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\x 0}; % <-- here
```

You can also replace the `{\x 0}` with a calculation `{\the\numexpr\x * 10}`, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206801/55879), i.e.

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,14}
\draw[gray!50, text=black] (0 cm,\x cm) -- (14 cm,\x cm) 
node at (-0.5 cm,\x cm) {\the\numexpr\x*10};
```

This has the advantage that you can replace `10` with any other number and get them numbered by twos or fives or whatever you want.

Either way, here's what the output looks like.

[image]

Comment: I wanna ask one more question related to previous one.

Comment: How can i keep a blank of 1cm between each bar in the above MWE.